# Google Analytics Actionscript 3.0 Custom Dimentions

Tags: actionscript-3, google-analytics

How can you track custom dimensions with actionscript 3.0? I don't see anything in the SDK.

Google's documentation on Custom Dimensions:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/customdimsmets

Google's doc on the Actionscript SDK:
http://gaforflash.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/com/google/analytics/GATracker.html

Note this will run in an AIR app and I don't want to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom tracker events. The first two arguments define the category and subcategory of the custom event (use any strings you like). The third and fourth can be used to record details about the particular event. For instance:

```
GAtracker.trackEvent("myCategory", "myAction", "width", stage.stageWidth);
GAtracker.trackEvent("myCategory", "myAction", "height", stage.stageheight);
```

Or:

```
GAtracker.trackEvent("myCategory", "myAction", "size", stage.stageWidth+","+stage.stageheight);
```

Comment: I assume then there is no way to track custom dimensions